# Unable to understand Python nested function

Tags: python, function, nested

Im trying to figure out ,how this code works without calling the function (num2)?

Example:

```
def num1(x):
   def num2(y):
      return x * y
   return num2
res = num1(10)

print(res(5))
```

Output:
50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented this to explain the functions.

```
# Defined function named num1 taking input 'x'
def num1(x):
    # Function 'num2' defined inside 'num1' taking input 'y'
   def num2(y):
    # Second function returning num1 input * num2 input
      return x * y
    # First function returning num2 is returned first
   return num2
# this is a variable for inputting to the nested functions.
# res = num1(num2)
res = num1(10)
# This is initializing num1 as 5
print(res(5))


# But it would be way easier...
def nums(x,y):
    return x * y

print(nums(5,10))
```

Answer (score 4):

It does call `num2`. That's what gets assigned to `res`, so `res(5)` calls it.

It might be slightly clearer if you rewrite `num1` to use a lambda expression (which is possible due to the simple nature of the function being defined and returned):

```
def num1(x):
    return lambda y: x * y

res = num1(10)  # res is a function that multiplies its argument by 10
print(res(5))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try to print res without giving any argument in it, you can see it behaves like a function shortly points a function address ;

```
def num1(x):
   def num2(y):
      return x * y
   return num2

res = num1(10)

print(res)
print(res(5))
```

Output;

```
<function num1.<locals>.num2 at 0x02DDBE38>
50
```